# Using theme options to change a border-radius value

Tags: php, css, theme-options

I'm developing a theme where I'm using theme options to allow users to set various things -- text size, background colour, link colour, etc.

The basic code I'm using for the options is in header.php and looks like this:

```
<?php 
$options = get_option('mytheme_theme_options');

if( isset( $options['backgroundcolour'] ) && ( !empty( $options['backgroundcolour'] ) ) )   
printf( "body {background: #%s;}", $options['backgroundcolour'] );

if( isset( $options['linkcolour'] ) && ( !empty( $options['linkcolour'] ) ) )   
printf( "a, a:link {color: #%s;}", $options['linkcolour'] );

?>
```

One of the options I want to set is a border radius for some chunks of content, which requires multiple declarations of the same value to work in all modern browsers:

```
.post {-webkit-border-radius: 8px; -moz-border-radius: 8px; border-radius: 8px;}
```

So, how do I get the PHP above to declare the same value three times in my CSS?

I should add that I'm not normally a PHP person; feeling a bit out of my depth here. :)

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use standard `echo` or `printf` with additional parameters. e.g.

```
if(isset($option['borderradius']) && (!empty($option['borderradius']))) {   
    $borderradius = '.post { ';
    $borderradius .= 'border-radius: ' . $option['borderradius'] . 'px; ';
    $borderradius .= '-webkit-border-radius: ' . $option['borderradius'] . 'px; ';
    $borderradius .= '-moz-border-radius: ' . $option['borderradius'] . 'px; ';
    $borderradius .= '}';

    echo $borderradius;
}

if(isset($option['borderradius']) && (!empty($option['borderradius']))) { 
    printf('.post { border-radius: %spx; -webkit-border-radius: %spx; -moz-border-radius: %spx; }', $option['borderradius'], $option['borderradius'], $option['borderradius']);
}
```

Comment: Hi Roman... Thanks for the reply, I'll try it out tomorrow and see if it works. Do you know, though, if there is any simpler/smaller way of getting the same result? I thought that it might be do-able with less code.

Comment: The second part only requires 3 lines of code. It's really basic php, so may answer here is no. Maybe you want to checkout the [PHP tutorial of Quakenet](http://tut.php-quake.net/en/concat.html) if need more help on PHP.

Comment: Hi Roman... Thanks, I hadn't realised that you'd given me two different ways to do the same thing, I thought it was all one big lump of code. :)

I went with the second way, worked great. Thanks!